# On Force Stop the notification is lost?

Tags: android, notifications, google-cloud-messaging

On Force Stop notification are not recieved because broadcast reciever will stop listening it. But is there any queue for GCM which store this notification. And would this notification be delivered once the app is opened or restart. Or the notification is lost?

Comment: Based on the [GCM documentatio](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#downstream-http-messages-json), there is a `time to live` parameter, you can set it for how long your message should be kept in GCM storage, the default value is 4 weeks, and the maximum `time to live` supported is 4 weeks.

Comment: I want to ask wether i would be able to recieve notification send to an app in the force stop mode. (Once the app is opened again)?

Comment: If your app was forced killed, your app is in online mode. So app needs to be reopen.

Comment: Yes app need to be reopen. But i am asking that whether the notification sent while the app was in force stop state will be delivered on reopening app or not?